# Como gravar stream RTSP

Tags: javascript, node.js, rtsp, mediarecorder

Estou utilizando o package `node-rtsp-stream` mais Websocket para fazer a transmissão de minha IP-Câmera, e a visualização ocorre bem, agora eu gostaria de saber como faço para gravar essa transmissão e não faço muita ideia de como fazer isso.

index.js no Server(NodeJS)

```js
const Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream'),
  stream = new Stream({
    name: 'Camera-Garagem',
    streamUrl: `rtsp://${meu_ip}:1030/user=${user}&password=${pass}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?`,
    wsPort: 5000
  })
```

index.html no Cliente

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="videoCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="jsmpeg.js"></script>
<script>
  const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000")
  const player = new jsmpeg(ws, {
    canvas: document.querySelector('#videoCanvas'),
    autoplay: true,
    audio: false,
    loop: true
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Podes dar uma olhada a esta biblioteca

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-recorder

```
const Recorder = require('node-rtsp-recorder').Recorder

var rec = new Recorder({
    url: 'rtsp://${meu_ip}:1030/user=${user}&password=${pass}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?',
    timeLimit: 60, // time in seconds for each segmented video file
    folder: '/node-rtsp-recorder/videos',
    name: 'cam1',
})
// Starts Recording
rec.startRecording();

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Stopping Recording')
    rec.stopRecording()
    rec = null
}, 300000)
```

Permite fazer o record da gravação e armazenar no disco do servidor, depois podes implementar algum tipo de lógica/rota para fazer o download desse video se necessário.

Comment: os arquivos gravados estão com 0 bytes, tem alguma ideia do que poder ser?